# How to compare two levels of one factor

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, method-comparison

I´ve run a GLMM model with the following variables:
Response variable: continuous (**with positive, negative and zero values**;
Explanatory variable: 1 factor with 6 levels **(DB, DF, NDB, NDF, BB, BF); individual as a random effect variable**

After running a lmer function, and checking the assumptions, I want to perform *a posteriori* specific comparisons. How do I do that?
I want to test for example if there is any difference between DF vs. DB. How do I write this in R??

**CODE IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
#Model:
m1 <- lmer(Vueltasmin ~ Condicion + (1 | Bicho), Datos)
summary(m1)

#Checking asusmptions: OK 

#Comparisons:
model.matrix.gls <- function(object, ...) {
  model.matrix(terms(object), data = getData(object), ...)
}
model.frame.gls <- function(object, ...) {
model.frame(formula(object), data = getData(object), ...)
}
terms.gls <- function(object, ...) {
  terms(model.frame(object), ...)
}


#Comparisons desired:
#DB-DF
#NDB-NDF
#BB-BF
#DB-BB
```

Here I show how the data plot looks like, and the comparisons desired. 
[image]

Thanks everyone for the help provided!

Comment: Check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/how-to-perform-post-hoc-test-on-lmer-model. And then google "lsmeans", there are several good tutorials out there.

Comment: Hi Dezmond Goff, I reviewed the link you posted, but that's for multiple comparisons and I want to perform specific ones

Comment: This is why I also suggested you look at a tutorial of lsmeans as there are ways to specify exactly what contrasts you are interested in. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjsmtiFsKbaAhUHqlQKHWNHB-IQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2kxQsw-sISiXmxlP2kTzj4

Comment: Hello Dezmond, thanks again. I don't quite understand the syntaxis of lsmeans, could you please tell me what should I type or how to adapt the example they give to mine? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the documentation for `emmeans::contrast`; it provides for such comparisons:

```
library("emmeans")
emm <- emmeans(m1, "Condicion")
contrast(emm, list(
    `DB-DF` = c(-1,1,0,0,0,0),
    `NDB-NDF` = c(0,0,-1,0,0,0),
    `BB-BF` = c(0,0,0,0,-1,1),
    `DB-BB` = c(-1,0,0,0,1,0)
))
```

Note: This is based on the assumption that the levels of `Condicion` are in the order given in the question. If they are not, then they are probably in alphabetical order (the default) and you need to either permute the 1s and -1s accordingly, or create

```
Datos$Condicion <- factor(as.character(Datos$Condicion),
    levels = c("DB", "DF", "NDB", "NDF", "BB", "BF"))
```

**and then re-fit the model** before using the above code to obtain the comparisons.

Comment: Dear rlv, thanks for your comment. I have two questions: trying to understand the syntaxis of emmeans, do you assign 1 and -1 to the pair of factor´s level you wish to compare? if so, shouldn´t be this comparison     `NDB-NDF` = c(0,0,-1,0,0,0) written as     `NDB-NDF` = c(0,0,-1,1,0,0) ? does it matter who is 1 and who -1?
The other question is about the order of the levels: they are categorical levels, they don´t have any order. I think I didn´t quite understand what you meant. Thanks in advance for your replay!!

Comment: BTW, you might want to add something like `adjust = “mvt”` so the P values are adjusted for multiplicity.

Comment: I see, I added the adjustment for multiplicity. I also see that the coefficients you posted are an outcome of 
coef(pairs(emm)) function. Regarding the order of the levels, that's still unclear.

Comment: They are coefficients to apply; so `c(1,-1,0,0,0,0)` means 1 times the first level plu -1 times the second level plus zero times the others - thus the first minus the second. To see the order of the levels, list `emm`. You need to move the 1s and -1s around accordingly. That’s what I was trying to say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small vignette. Note the `lsmeans` package has been deprecated in favor of the `emmeans` package, but they have very similar syntax for this simple example.

```
require(lme4)
require(emmeans)

N <- 1000
M <- 200
Condicion <- as.factor(sample(1:6, 1000, replace=T))
X <- model.matrix(~Condicion)
Bicho <- as.factor(sample(rep(1:200, each=5), 1000, replace=F))
Z <- model.matrix(~Bicho+0)
Vueltasmin <- X %*% matrix(rnorm(6, 0, 5), nrow=6, ncol=1) + Z %*% matrix(rnorm(M, 0, 10), nrow=M, ncol=1) + rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

mod <- lmer(Vueltasmin ~ Condicion + (1 | Bicho))
summary(mod)

mod.emm <- emmeans(mod, "Condicion")
mod.pair <- pairs(mod.emm)
mod.comp <- mod.pair[c(1, 4, 10, 15)]
mod.comp
```

They key is that after you call `pairs` on the `emmobj`, you index for the contrasts of interest (in your case, 1, 4, 10 and 15). The p-values are then readjusted for the smaller number of comparisons.

Comment: Dear Dezmond Goff, thanks for the example! I´m trying my best to look for information on what every line means, because I have a limited understanding about R coding.

Comment: The first section is just generating fake data according to the specification of a LMM. Only the last 4 lines after model fitting are important.